# What did CPU time and disk space cost at a CDC 6600 Data Center?

Tags: cost, cdc, timesharing

In the mid-1970s,there was a big time sharing CDC service center in Waltham, MA.  I'm curious what it cost to run computer jobs there.

> (My long winded story follows) In 1976, I had a summer job of "shuffling" decks of cards to pass to a [CDC 6600](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDC_6600) machine. My employer had this great big engineering simulation that took 30 minutes to run.
>
> My job was to,
>
> 1. Prepare a deck of cards to pass to the machine,
> 2. Wait for 20-40 minutes for the operator to call my company's name,
> 3. Call the boss back at the office with the results,
> 4. He'd dwell on the results for a moment or two and tell me something like, "Let's try .1% Cesium."
> 5. I'd type up a card for .1% Cesium, put it in the right place in the deck and repeat.
>
> It was a good deal for the boss.  He could sit at the office and do
> his smart PhD type stuff while a minimum wage summer student (me) was
> doing the sitting around the data center waiting.

The program was big and my deck was small so I believe we had to be paying for disk space, to go with the CPU time.  What did it cost?

Comment: You show a quote from something. Can you edit your question (don't add info in comments) and add the source of the quote. Thanks.

Comment: Yes.  I see. There is no provision for breaking out a bunch of the text to make it clear it is back story and not part of the question.  To a large extent, it is a quote but I am quoting myself.  When I am telling the story, I generally compare myself to "The feeders of Vaal" in the Star Trek episode, [The Apple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Apple_(Star_Trek:_The_Original_Series)).  My job was to feed cards to the big computer the same way the villagers fed fruit to Vaal.

Comment: The answer can be anything from free to 100 USD/sec. It can't be answered without knowing setup, business relation and how accounting was done, if at all. Prices varied extreme between installations and services. There is no valid guess unless someone can come up with a price list (and relevant discounts) for exact that site (where was it) at exact that time (prices did change quite a lot over time) for that setup (Second and a MiB prices vary depending on device) and that customer (having custom contracts was standard).

Comment: Do you recall the name of the computer bureau?  And did they offer 'timesharing' in the more common sense of shared interactive access, or was this simply multiprogramming?

Comment: @Raffzahn When you mentioned variable pricing, I thought of the developer that would do his work in the overnight, only quitting when they threw him out at 5AM for system maintenance.  He did that because that is when the computer time was cheapest.  If somebody has a price list, that would be golden but vague recollections of what a company would have paid for a given amount of time, etc. would be appreciated.

Comment: @another-dave I believe it was called a "CDC Service Center." Control Data Corp figured out that not everybody that needs fast computers has $15 million lying around to buy one so they set up data centers where there was demand, such as on Route 128, outside Boston.  I was a minimum-wage worker-bee so I was not privy to all of the products offered.  I only saw batch processing but I heard rumors of modem connections so maybe it was timesharing.

Comment: Oh, actually run by CDC. I was thinking you meant a third-party bureau.